# Не работает javascript и jQuery в Вордпресс, если не авторизован

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Всем доброго времени суток.
Сайт на Вордпресс.
Есть секция, сделанная на Элементоре.
В ней выведены кастомные посты на своем шаблоне с помощью Pods.
К ней есть jQuery-код, убирающий ненужные блоки по выбору страны, а потом и города.
Проблемма — все работает, если я авторизован в админке.
Но вне админки jQuery не работает напрочь.
Все $ заменил на jQuery.
Подозреваю, что при авторизации вордпресс подключает правильно / правильный jQuery, а после выхода загружается неправильный jQuery.
jQuery подключен к теме старый, 1.12.
В function.php ни дочерней, ни родительской темы подключение скриптов не нашел, поэтому подключил новый jQuery через https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js»>

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Спасибо всем, кто ответит.
Страница с проблеммой - https://vorwarts.hosting-development.info/my-jobs/

Даже этот простой код с alert работает только если авторизован в админке, вне админки не работает ! -

```js
  choose.onclick = function() {
    alert('java чистый работает !!!');
  };
```

В консоли без ошибок. 
Отменял и jquery-migrate, в хеде jquery-migrate не отображался, jquery подключался новый - Без результата.
Код скрипта не привожу, если он работает при авторизации в админке, значит он рабочий) 
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Зря отменили jquery-migrate. У вас где-то в коде прописано условие типа - if(is_user_logged_in()) или if(admin) и подключение скрипта. Можете просто в файле function.php что лежит в /wp-content/themes/(ваша активная тема)/ написать хук и переподключить jQuery

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method', 11 );
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

вот тут подробнее https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Но с этим кодом перестало работать даже авторизованным...

Comment: и jquery-migrate  уже давно вернул назад)

Comment: Нашел. Странный конфликт с Элементором. По отношению к блокам, созданным без Элементора, все работает. Может, кому-то пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Странный конфликт с Элементором. По отношению к блокам, созданным без Элементора, все работает. Может, кому-то пригодится

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с такой проблемой недавно. Причина была в плагине Pagespeed Ninja. Чистка кэша не помогла, отключил плагин целиком. Если всё работало, а потом появилась такая проблема, сначала попробуйте отключить все плагины, которые "ускоряют" работу сайта